# cant access dynamically created obj propery of an array in anglarjs2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have an items array like :-

```
this.itemList = [
  { id: 1, name: 'a', address: 'as dasf a' },
  { id: 2, name: 'b', address: 'as dasf a' },
  { id: 3, name: 'c', address: 'as dasf a' }
];
```

one headers array is :-

```
this.headers = [
  { name: 'id', show: true },
  { name: 'name', show: true },
  { name: 'address', show: false }
];
```

I am doing something like :-

```
let obj = this.headers[0].name; // this is coming as 'id'
console.log(this.itemList[0].id) // this showing as 1
```

this is correct, but when i am doing :-

```
console.log(this.itemList[0].obj) // it says undefined, why?
```

Is there any way i can get that value?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing it like :

```
this.itemList[0][obj]
```

---

**Reason :**

**Why this is not working ?**

```
this.itemList[0].obj 
// this will not work coz it will try to find 'obj' as key in itemList[0]
// so it will return undefined
```

**But this :**

```
this.itemList[0][obj]
// But in this one obj considered as varible and replace with its value
// so it will become this.itemList[0].id / this.itemList[0]['id']
```

Comment: You should explain why you can write this. It will help the OP (and other users) to understand.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ , I was adding the explanation but posted the answer first :) , Thanks BTW

Comment: Thanks a lot man, can you explain why it was not working like the way i was doing

Comment: @AlokKamboj , I have already explained it in answer , please go through the comment also , Hope that will clear your doubts

Comment: @AlokKamboj , will you please accept and upvote the answer?

Comment: @AlokKamboj , Thanks.